# @Transient - Why data is getting saved in Database?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, h2

I have an entity variable annotated with @Transient like below. Which means it should not be stored in the Database.

```
@Transient
private String passwordConfirm;
```

But when I go to H2-Console, I can see the data is saved there.

[image]

Why so? and How can I avoid it?

Comment: Could you include your entity, your DAO/Repository, or anything that you're using to store object into the database? it's rather impossible to guess something mystically, from this one annotation, that you've posted in your question. Include [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're probably using `@org.springframework.data.annotation.Transient`.

Change it to the right import: `@javax.persistence.Transient`

This will do the job.

`@javax.persistence.Transient` is used by the persistence provider (eg.: Hibernate). The persistence provider looks for JPA spec annotations. `@org.springframework.data.annotation.Transient` is not a part of the JPA spec, so, the persistence provider ignores it.

The `@org.springframework.data.annotation.Transient` is intended to be used when Spring Data is the actual ORM. Some examples are Spring Data Elasticsearch and Spring Data MongoDB. These Spring Data implementations use the `@org.springframework.data.annotation.Transient` just like Hibernate uses  the `@javax.persistence.Transient` - not mapping the marked field into the database.

Comment: Man...! you nailed it. You are right. That fixed it. But, can you please also put 2-3 lines for - Why it behaves like that if use spring import instead of javax? And why spring has implemented it that way?

Comment: @AjayKumar sure, explanation added. Answer updated.

Comment: Nice. That clears the dust. Thanks for short and precise explanation. Keep up the good work at this lovely SO community. Many thanks again.